# Failed to instantiate module 'minovateApp' is not available

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower

### Failed to instantiate module minovateApp

I am getting this error while building the angular project. I have installed ng-resource to my project:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module minovateApp due to:
> Error: [$injector:nomod] **Module 'minovateApp' is not available!** You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/nomod?p0=minovateApp at file:///E:/InnovationBeesprojects/cargobees-
> .....

This is my index.html code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="minovateApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="no-js {{containerClass}}">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cargobees - Admin Dashboard</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

    <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-bootstrap-colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-bootstrap-nav-tree/dist/abn_tree.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/chosen/chosen.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/intro.js/introjs.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/rickshaw/rickshaw.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-toastr/dist/angular-toastr.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-ui-select/dist/select.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-ui-tree/dist/angular-ui-tree.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/animate.css/animate.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/material-design-iconic-font/dist/css/material-design-iconic-font.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/morrisjs/morris.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/ng-table/dist/ng-table.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/ng-tags-input/ng-tags-input.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/ngImgCrop/compile/minified/ng-img-crop.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/weather-icons/css/weather-icons.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/weather-icons/css/weather-icons.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/weather-icons/css/weather-icons-wind.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/weather-icons/css/weather-icons-wind.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/dragular/dist/dragular.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/magnific-popup/dist/magnific-popup.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angucomplete-alt/angucomplete-alt.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/json-formatter/dist/json-formatter.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap-social/bootstrap-social.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/c3/c3.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/css/datetimepicker.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-hovercard/dist/angular-hovercard.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/layout.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </head>
  <body id="minovate" class="{{main.settings.navbarHeaderColor}} {{main.settings.activeColor}} {{containerClass}} header-fixed aside-fixed rightbar-hidden appWrapper" ng-class="{'header-fixed': main.settings.headerFixed, 'header-static': !main.settings.headerFixed, 'aside-fixed': main.settings.asideFixed, 'aside-static': !main.settings.asideFixed, 'rightbar-show': main.settings.rightbarShow, 'rightbar-hidden': !main.settings.rightbarShow}">

    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Application content -->
    <div id="wrap" ui-view autoscroll="false"></div>

    <!-- Page Loader -->
    <div id="pageloader" page-loader></div>


    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
     <script>
       (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
       (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
       m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
       })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

       ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
       ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.9/firebase.js"></script>
    <script>
      var config = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyD3ElSyvFYfVVXQlNimsfi_d7edi_VN_V8",
        authDomain: "cargo-ee422.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://cargo-ee422.firebaseio.com",
        storageBucket: "cargo-ee422.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "100271283421"
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>
    <script src="googlescripts/service-worker.js"></script>
    <script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=weather,geometry,visualization,places,drawing&sensor=false&language=en&v=3.17'></script>

    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/oldieshim.js -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->

    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap-colorpicker/js/bootstrap-colorpicker-module.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap-nav-tree/dist/abn_tree_directive.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-chosen-localytics/chosen.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-datatables/dist/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-datatables/dist/plugins/bootstrap/angular-datatables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-datatables/dist/plugins/colreorder/angular-datatables.colreorder.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-datatables/dist/plugins/columnfilter/angular-datatables.columnfilter.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-datatables/dist/plugins/colvis/angular-datatables.colvis.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-datatables/dist/plugins/fixedcolumns/angular-datatables.fixedcolumns.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-datatables/dist/plugins/fixedheader/angular-datatables.fixedheader.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-datatables/dist/plugins/scroller/angular-datatables.scroller.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-datatables/dist/plugins/tabletools/angular-datatables.tabletools.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/d3/d3.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-flot/angular-flot.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-fontawesome/dist/angular-fontawesome.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-fullscreen/src/angular-fullscreen.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-simple-logger/dist/angular-simple-logger.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/lodash/lodash.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/intro.js/intro.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-intro.js/src/angular-intro.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ipsum/dist/ipsum.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-leaflet-directive/dist/angular-leaflet-directive.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/masonry/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/ev-emitter/ev-emitter.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery-bridget/jquery-bridget.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-masonry/angular-masonry.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-momentjs/angular-momentjs.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/rickshaw/rickshaw.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-rickshaw/rickshaw.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-smart-table/dist/smart-table.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-toastr/dist/angular-toastr.tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-translate-storage-cookie/angular-translate-storage-cookie.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-translate-storage-local/angular-translate-storage-local.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-select/dist/select.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-tree/dist/angular-ui-tree.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-base64/angular-base64.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/flot-spline/js/jquery.flot.spline.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/flot.tooltip/js/jquery.flot.tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/html.sortable/dist/html.sortable.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery.easy-pie-chart/dist/angular.easypiechart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery.inputmask/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery.sparkline/index.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/leaflet-heat/dist/leaflet-heat.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/leaflet-plugins/control/Distance.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/leaflet-plugins/control/Layers.Load.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/leaflet-plugins/control/Permalink.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/leaflet-plugins/control/Permalink.Layer.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/leaflet-plugins/control/Permalink.Line.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/leaflet-plugins/control/Permalink.Marker.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/leaflet-plugins/layer/Icon.Canvas.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/leaflet-plugins/layer/Layer.Deferred.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/leaflet-plugins/layer/Marker.Rotate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/leaflet-plugins/layer/Marker.Text.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/leaflet-plugins/layer/OpenStreetBugs.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/leaflet-plugins/layer/vector/GPX.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/leaflet-plugins/layer/vector/GPX.Speed.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/leaflet-plugins/layer/vector/KML.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/leaflet-plugins/layer/vector/OSM.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/leaflet-plugins/layer/tile/Bing.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/leaflet-plugins/layer/tile/Google.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/leaflet-plugins/layer/tile/Yandex.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/eve-raphael/eve.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/raphael/raphael.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/morrisjs/morris.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/ng-bs-daterangepicker/src/ng-bs-daterangepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/ng-table/dist/ng-table.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/ng-tags-input/ng-tags-input.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/ngImgCrop/compile/minified/ng-img-crop.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/oclazyload/dist/ocLazyLoad.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/textAngular/dist/textAngular-rangy.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/textAngular/dist/textAngular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/textAngular/dist/textAngular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/dragular/dist/dragular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/magnific-popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/flow.js/dist/flow.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/ng-flow/dist/ng-flow.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-base64-upload/src/angular-base64-upload.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angucomplete-alt/angucomplete-alt.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/json-formatter/dist/json-formatter.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/myforce-angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/dist/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/c3/c3.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-chart/angular-chart.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/js/datetimepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/js/datetimepicker.templates.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-date-time-input/src/dateTimeInput.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-hovercard/dist/angular-hovercard.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-daterangepicker/js/angular-daterangepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-websocket/dist/angular-websocket.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->

    <!-- endbuild -->

   
</body>
</html>
```

This is my app.js

```js
var app = angular
  .module('minovateApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ngMessages',
    'picardy.fontawesome',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.router',
    'ui.utils',
    'angular-loading-bar',
    'angular-momentjs',
    'FBAngular',
    'lazyModel',
    'toastr',
    'angularBootstrapNavTree',
    'oc.lazyLoad',
    'ui.select',
    'ui.tree',
    'textAngular',
    'colorpicker.module',
    'angularFileUpload',
    'ngImgCrop',
    'datatables',
    'datatables.bootstrap',
    'datatables.colreorder',
    'datatables.colvis',
    'datatables.tabletools',
    'datatables.scroller',
    'datatables.columnfilter',
    'ui.grid',
    'ui.grid.resizeColumns',
    'ui.grid.edit',
    'ui.grid.moveColumns',
    'ngTable',
    'smart-table',
    'angular-flot',
    'angular-rickshaw',
    'easypiechart',
    'uiGmapgoogle-maps',
    'ui.calendar',
    'ngTagsInput',
    'pascalprecht.translate',
    'ngMaterial',
    'localytics.directives',
    'leaflet-directive',
    'wu.masonry',
    'ipsum',
    'angular-intro',
    'dragularModule',
    'base64',
    'flow',
    'naif.base64',
    'rorymadden.date-dropdowns',
    'angucomplete-alt',
    'jsonFormatter',
    'angularjs-dropdown-multiselect',
    'ui.grid',
    'ui.grid.selection',
    'angularChart',
    'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker',
    'ui.dateTimeInput',
    'yaru22.hovercard',
    'daterangepicker',
    'ngWebSocket'
  ]);
```

Comment: Where is `angular.module('minovateApp',[])` in the code ?? I dont see it anywhere. can you share `app.js`

Comment: I have added my app.js code Plz take a look

Comment: Can you make sure that the path of `app.js` is correct. The code seems correct